# cannot backup with dd

Tags: dd

using dd to create part. image I always get the msg that there is no Storage available
on the output file.
my cmd. is:  sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc2.disk1.img
device sdb1 is my Ubuntu 11.10 ext4 root partition 54 Gb. in size.
device sdc2 is an empty ext4 partition 80 Gb. in size on an other external hard drive.
Same results if devices are mounted or unmounted or if I run dd as root user.

Comment: You should mount `/dev/sdc2` somewhere, say on `/mnt`, then use as output a new file on `/mnt`, for example `/mnt/file.image`.

Comment: Also I'd like to mention that `dd` is a really dangerous command which does no "sanity checks" or anything to prevent you from destroying your data; and in addition it is ran with superuser privileges. I wouldn't try to guess the correct syntax to use it via trial-and-error process (this `/dev/sdc2.disk1.img` thingie - is it "hmm... maybe that's how I can write to disk1.img file on the /dev/sdc2 filelsystem", right? :) )

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are trying to put the file in the /dev directory, which is a tmpfs that holds only a limited amount of files in ram.  If you want to put the file in /dev/sdc2, then you have to mount it somewhere and put the file there.

Answer (score 0):

dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=~/Desktop/file.img

then do:

dd if=~/Desktop/file.img of=/dev/whateverdevice bs=XM

(where x is the amount of Megabytes per block). Make sure the destination device is unmounted.